# New to awk and sed, How could I improve this? Multiple sed and awk commands

Tags: bash, sed, awk, xxd

This is the script I've constructed

- It takes a list of files according to the extension supplied as an argument.
- It then removes everything before the pattern 00000000: in those files.
- The pattern 00000000: is preceded by the string `<pre>`, it then removes those five first characters.
- The script then removes the last three lines of the file
- The script the outputs only the hexdump data of the file.
- The script runs xxd to convert the hexdump to a file.jpg

```
    if [[ $# -eq 0 ]] ; then
        echo 'Run script as ./hexconv ext'
        exit 0
    fi

    for file in *.$1
    do
        filename=$(basename $file)
        extension="${filename##*.}"
        filename="${filename%.*}"

        sed -n '/00000000:/,$p' $file | sed '1s/^.....//' | head -n -3 | awk '{print $2" "$3" "$4" "$5" "$6" "$7" "$8" "$9" "$10" "$11" "$12" "$13" "$14" "$15" "$16" "$17}' | xxd -p -r > $filename.jpg
    done
```

It works as I want it too, but I suspect there are things to improve it by, but alas, I am a novice in the use of awk and sed.

Excerpt from file

```
<th>response-head:</th>
<td>HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 15 Dec 2013 04:27:04 GMT
Server: PWS/8.0.18
X-Px: ms h0-s34.p6-lhr ( h0-s35.p6-lhr), ht-d h0-s35.p6-lhr.cdngp.net
Etag: &quot;4556354-9fbf8-4e40387aadfc0&quot;
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0, max-age=0
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 654328
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Last-Modified: Thu, 15 Aug 2013 21:55:19 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<hr/>
<pre>00000000:  ff  d8  ff  e0  00  10  4a  46  49  46  00  01  01  01  00  48  ......JFIF.....H
00000010:  00  48  00  00  ff  e1  00  18  45  78  69  66  00  00  49  49  .H......Exif..II
00000020:  2a  00  08  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  ff  ed  *...............
00000030:  00  48  50  68  74  73  68  70  20  33  2e  30  00  .HPhotoshop 3.0.
00000040:  38  42  49  4d  04  04  00  00  00  00  00  1c  01  5a  00  8BIM..........Z.
00000050:  03  1b  25  47  1c  02  00  00  02  00  02  00  38  42  49  4d  ..%G........8BIM
00000060:  04  25  00  00  00  00  00  10  fc  e1  89  c8  b7  c9  78  .%.............x
00000070:    34  62  34  07  58  77  eb  ff  e1  03  a5  68  74  74  70  /4b4.Xw.....http
00000080:  3a    6e  73  2e  61  64  62  65  2e  63  6d  ://ns.adobe.com/
00000090:  78  61  70  31  2e  30  00  3c  78  70  61  63  6b  xap/1.0/.&lt;?xpack
000000a0:  65  74  20  62  65  67  69  6e  3d  22  ef  bb  bf  22  20  69  et begin="..." i
000000b0:  64  3d  22  57  35  4d  30  4d  70  43  65  68  69  48  7a  72  d="W5M0MpCehiHzr
000000c0:  65  53  7a  4e  54  63  7a  6b  63  39  64  22  3e  20  3c  eSzNTczkc9d"?&gt; &lt;
000000d0:  78  3a  78  6d  70  6d  65  74  61  20  78  6d  6c  6e  73  3a  x:xmpmeta xmlns:
000000e0:  78  3d  22  61  64  62  65  3a  6e  73  3a  6d  65  74  61  x="adobe:ns:meta
000000f0:    22  20  78  3a  78  6d  70  74  6b  3d  22  41  64  62  /" x:xmptk="Adob
00000100:  65  20  58  4d  50  20  43  72  65  20  35  2e  30  2d  63  e XMP Core 5.0-c
00000110:  30  36  31  20  36  34  2e  31  34  30  39  34  39  2c  20  32  061 64.140949, 2
00000120:  30  31  30  31  32  30  37  2d  31  30  3a  35  37  3a  010/12/07-10:57:
```

Comment: This is a code review question, rather than a specific problem. It doesn't belong on Stack Overflow, but may be a fit for [Code Review SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although [@CodeGnome](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1301972/codegnome) is right and this might belong to [Code Review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), here you go anyway:

1. <strike>Slightly more efficient to combine the multiple `sed` commands into one, for example:</strike>

   ```
   sed -n -e 's/^<pre>//' -e '/00000000:/,$p'
   ```

   *I decided to retract this part, as I'm not all that sure it's any better or clearer. Your version is fine, except that `s/^<pre>//` is better than `s/^.....//`.*
2. Use `exit 1` when checking the number of arguments to signal an error
3. What is `for file in *.` there? Iterate for all files ending with a dot? Typo?
4. Unless you're 100% sure the filenames will *never* contain spaces, you should quote them, but don't quote where you don't need, for example:

   ```
   filename=$(basename "$file")  # need to quote
   extension=${filename##*.}     # no need, 
   filename=${filename%.*}       # no need
   sed ... "$file"               # need to quote
   ... | xxd > "$filename".jpg   # need to quote
   ```
5. The last `awk` could be shorter and less error prone as a loop:

   ```
   ... | awk '{printf $2; for (i=3; i<=17; ++i) printf " " $i; print ""}'
   ```

It seems you want to learn. You might be interested in this other answer too: [What are the rules to write robust shell scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20034614/what-are-the-rules-to-write-robust-shell-scripts/20035079#20035079)

Comment: sed -n -e 's/^<pre>//' -e '/00000000:/,$p' is not correct if it appear at least a second time in the end of the file. The only way (in 1 sed) is to buffer the content, remove first occurence than print. if buffer is used, remove the 3 trailer line is also possible avoiding the tail -3 and extracting column also bu no convertion easily made in sed

Comment: You're right, it would not be correct in general, but in this specific case it works: he won't have another `<pre>` in there, and if he did, he would want to eliminate it too. In any case, I scratched out that point (see my update) because it was a bit dodgy anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The error message should be sent to stderr, should not hard-code the name of the script in case you rename it later, and should exit with a nonzero value.

```
if (( ! $# )); then
  echo >&2 "Run script as '$0' \$extension"
  exit 1
fi
```

If you're going to put the `then` on the same line as the `if`, then you should put the `do` on the same line as the `for`, too, for consistency:

```
for file in *.$1; do
```

Using `file` for the full name and `filename` for the basename is confusing variable name choice.  I would use `basename` for the variable, to match the operation. And you need to quote the parameter expansion:

```
    basename=$(basename "$file")
```

But you don't need to quote the right hand side of an assignment:

```
    extension=${basename##*.}
```

The part of a filename without the extension is sometimes called the `root` (in vi and csh `:`-modifiers, you get it with `:r`)... using that name would be less confusing than changing an existing variable and reusing it:

```
    root=${basename%.*}
```

As far as the actual pipeline, I would reorder it to put the `head` before the `awk`, since the `sed` and the `head` are all about what lines to print out and should be grouped together before the `awk` which modifies those selected lines. I would also use a loop and `printf` to make the `awk` a little more wieldy:

```
    sed -n '/0\{8\}:/,$p' "$file" | 
      head -n -3 | 
      awk '{ printf "%s", $2; for (f=3;f<=17;++f) { printf " %s", $f }; print "" }' | 
      xxd -p -r > "$root.jpg"
done
```